# jQuery explode string like PHP

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I was looking on some SO questions and the jQuery area to try to use the similar feature in PHP using `explode` which will just explode a string given into it's pieces from a type of substring.

This is the code I used:

```
var users = // AJAX CALL TO GET USERS
var usersArr = users.split();
```

I looked at the `w3` tutorial for splitting strings and this was the JavaScript type, and even that didn't work.

Error message:

> index.js:45 Uncaught TypeError: users.split is not a function

Comment: split()  should be split(',') or the delimiter of your choice

Comment: AJAX is `asynchronous`!.

Comment: What output did you get and where there any errors in the console?

Comment: It should be `.split('')` (empty string). But make sure that your ajax request has returned from server (common pit fall)

Comment: Could you post a full code sample. If you're doing `var users = $.ajax();` then `users` will be a deferred object, not a string, hence the error you get. You should use the callback of the AJAX request. Also `split()` requires a parameter to break the string by.

Comment: You need to add delimiter in `split` like `split("_")`

Comment: `I looked at the w3 tutorial for splitting strings and this was the JavaScript type, and even that didn't work.` Never use W3Schools for anything. Their articles are often outdated and as you've seen, occasionally completely wrong. Always use [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript)

Comment: [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) not quite a duplicate but one of your issues

Comment: I have given it a paramater, the `users` variable is gotten by AJAX getting the usernames and dispalying them by `<br/>`, I want to remove the `<br/>` from the string so that I only have the usernames.

Comment: Also see [How can I debug my JavaScript code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/988363/how-can-i-debug-my-javascript-code)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

just like PHP you can do but with different method.

```
var str = "How are you doing today?"
var res =  str.split(" ");
```

> access this way : "String :" + res[0]+"  "+res[1]+" "+res[4]+" "

> output : How are today?

Answer (score 2):

Since Ajax is `asynchronous`, you have to set `users` variable inside the `success` callback of the Ajax call and then split the string.

It can be don like this.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "url-to-the-page",
    success: function(data) {
        var users = data;
        var usersArr = users.split(";"); // if semicolon is the separator.
    }
});
```